# How to make/use variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables

I know that in MySQL you can do something like `SELECT foo AS bar FROM TABLE t;` I'm trying to do something to the effect of `SELECT command1 FROM table1 AS foo, command2 FROM table2 AS bar, (foo-bar) AS difference;` but MySQL doesn't let me do that. Is there a way to do this in MySQL or will I need to get some extension? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `foo - bar` would be a select field which must come before the one from clause. you also should be joining the tables. post your sample data structures with data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Schema

```
create table t1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null
);

create table t2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    descr varchar(100) not null
);

insert t1(thing) values ('cat'),('dog');
insert t2(descr) values ('meow'),('likes bones');
```

### Query

```
select t1.thing,t2.descr into @var1,@var2 
from t1 
join t2 
on t2.id=t1.id 
where t1.id=2; -- to avoid Error 1172: Result consisted of more than one row
```

### View vars

```
select @var1 as thing,@var2 as descr;
+-------+-------------+
| thing | descr       |
+-------+-------------+
| dog   | likes bones |
+-------+-------------+
```

The important part of selecting into vars like above is to limit the resultset to 1 row max.