# How to make Foreign key work in MyIsam

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship, myisam

I'm working on a project and almost have done a lot of work on a hosting site which is not supporting InnoDB, I tested my application on localerver for relationships between the table and all working fine, now for further work I have to get back to the hosting site but after all the searching i'm unable to figure out a way to make relationships in MyIsam as it won't support foreign key. I came across few things which made me think that may be I can achive it by using indexes or REFRENCES, but HOW? it was not clear enough to implement and work it out.
I'll really appreciate if any one can quickly guide me on this with proper working. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's a little bit of work, but you can do this using triggers, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39365525/6248528) or [here](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html). Although you might want to consider changing your hosting site, because there is other stuff that you cannot do in MyISAM (probably most importantly transactions), and, in case that site doesn't support innodb not by choice but because it is too old, because a 10 years old MySQL might give you more troubles than missing foreign key support.

Comment: Good grief!  Move to a hosting site that supports InnoDB.  MyISAM is gone from the latest release.

Comment: @RickJames Can you suggest any? coz i'm unable to find one.