# How to ignore foreign constraints and add NULL instead

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which share same primary/foreign key for ID:

- Table1: `PRIMARY KEY (id));`
- Table2: `FOREIGN KEY (ident) REFERENCES table1(id);`

I am trying to create a **trigger** in order to let me insert new row with non existing primary key and set on that field NULL but i am getting:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails error.

How can i solve this issue ?

this is what i tried but so far:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT on table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.ident!= (
    SELECT  ident 
    FROM dimos
    WHERE ident NOT IN (
        SELECT  id   
        FROM    table1        
    )
)
THEN 
    SET NEW.ident = 'NULL';
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

so i expect to get all field in a row expert the foreign key, foreign key must be null!

Comment: You may have your trigger backwards: if a foreign key on table2 refers to table1 (which means when you change something in table2, the value has to already exist in table1), a trigger on table1 does not help. Also, while your condition is unclear, keep in mind that `null != ident` is always false. Also `'null'` is something different than `null`. Also, while it is not clear if that is what you mean: if `ident` is the primary key of table2, it cannot be `null` by definition. For the proper syntax see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34004118) (and set null instead of `signal`)